# Can i put profile picture and cover photo in phpfox member index?

Tags: phpfox

I need to put profile pic and cover photo on left block in member index I have try every single method but useless

So any help please

Actually phpfox 4.7

Please admins don't close the post I really need help with this tutorial

Here is a screenshots
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TewzF.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/yI0FG.jpg

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please consider editing your question with the relevant code, what you've tried so far and how that failed to meet your expectations. It will be easier for someone to fix your problem that way, than expecting them to do all the work for you instead.

Comment: I have add screenshots so any help please

Comment: So anyone can help me please

Answer (score 0):

Go to ***AdminCP - Appearance - Blocks - Add Block***

**Now Fill the form as below**

- **Product** = Core
  **Module** = Profile
  **Title** = Anything(wont display public)
  **Type** = PHP Block File
  **Page** = Member Home Page (core. index-member)
  **Component** = header (for cover photo), logo (for logo)
  **Placement View Sample Layout** = Block 1 (This will place the image on left block

Comment: how can i contact you please ?